# Make two amount inputs equal to a balance input on blur

Tags: jquery, payment

Trying to have two inputs be equal to another. For example, the user would input an amount in the balance box, then whatever was input into "Amount 1" or "Amount 2" would make the other box be equal to the balance. I hope that wasn't too confusing.

Here is where I am at currently:

```
$('input[id*="amount"]').bind("blur", function() {
    var balance = $('#balance').val()
       ,amount1 = $('#amount-1').val()
       ,amount2 = $('#amount-2').val()
       ,inputVal = $(this).val();

    if(amount1 + amount2 != balance){
        $(this).closest('input[id*="amount"]').val(balance-inputVal);
    }
});
```

I tried using next() with no luck; closest() just populates the currently selected input, when I would like the opposite input to be populated. Appreciate any help.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="balance">Balance Due</label>
    <input type="text" size="20" id="balance" name="balance" />
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="amount-1">Amount 1</label>
    <input type="text" size="20" id="amount-1" name="amount-1" />
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="amount-2">Amount 2</label>
    <input type="text" size="20" id="amount-2" name="amount-2" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see the page in action?

Comment: @andrew-buchan sorry no, it is on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel you need this solution

```
if(amount1 + amount2 != balance){
        $('input[id*="amount"]').not(this).val(balance-inputVal);
    }
```

Please try with this

http://jsfiddle.net/ashukasama/n23mB/